# Create tag for Java-8 on SuperUser

Tags: discussion, tags

I don't have 300 rep, but I'd like the java-8 tag to be created, for the same reason that the java-7 exists.

Comment: There isn't a big enough difference or demand for this tag.

Comment: [tag:java-7] shouldn't have existed in the first place. Its creation was a mistake.

Answer (score 5):

Just use the [java](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/java) tag. There were only 9 questions with java-7 and sincerely all of them had [java](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/java) or equivalent. There isn't a need to atomize the java tag.

Comment: Frankly, do we even need a [tag:java-7] tag? with 23 questions as of June 2012 (data collected 09/09/2014), shouldn't we just burninate it?

Comment: I've merged `java-7` into `java` CC: @Mureinik